# How to split and join array in C++ for UDP?

Tags: c++, udp

I have a byte array like this:

```
lzo_bytep out; // my byte array
size_t uncompressedImageSize = 921600;

out = (lzo_bytep) malloc((uncompressedImageSize + 
          uncompressedImageSize / 16 + 64 + 3));
wrkmem = (lzo_voidp) malloc(LZO1X_1_MEM_COMPRESS);

// Now the byte array has 802270 bytes
r = lzo1x_1_compress(imageData, uncompressedImageSize,
        out, &out_len, wrkmem);
```

How can I split it into smaller parts under 65,535 bytes (the byte array is one large image which I want to sent over UDP which has upper limit 65,535 bytes) and then join those small chunks back into a continuous array?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The problem with doing this is that the UDP packets can arrive out or order, or be dropped. Use TCP for this; that's what it's for.

Comment: But still, I would like to do this with UDP. I only send the whole image once then I send only pixels that have changed so the following packets will be smaller and will fit into one UDP packet. I need UDP because it is faster than TCP and I need speed.

Comment: @Richard: You're not going to be able to implement a connection that does this correctly that operates any faster than TCP does. Open a TCP connection to send over the initial big chunk, and then use UDP for updates, (assuming that if any of the updates are lost or destroyed, you can recover from that; UDP packets can be lost or destroyed). This is what game servers who need this kind of low latency do -- i.e. sound files and such are transferred over TCP, but player positions and such are transmitted over UDP (i.e. CounterStrike servers).

Comment: True in theory.  Less so in practice.

Comment: @Richard: I think what John means is that it's uncommon for UDP packets to arrive out of order (which is true) -- nevertheless, if it happens your app can't explode.

Comment: @Billy ONeal Well, I could append a number like 0,1,2... to the end of the byte array and then on the receiving end wait for all UDP packets and sort them according to that appended number but I guess I will use TCP for the first image and use UDP for updates.

Comment: If all packets do not arrive (which hopefully will happen very rarely) I could just throw an exception and try sending the initial big image again until all gets through and after that just start sending pixels that have changed.

Comment: @Richard: How do you know the packet has not arrived? If the packet is lost neither party is notified of the loss.

Comment: @Billy ONeal Actually I don't know yet. I guess I could sent an integer 0 to indicate that a transfer of a complete image has began, then send intiger 1 to indicate the transfer should be over. I would count how many packets I've received between the 0 and 1 integers arrived and if the amount was correct (given the width, height and num. of layers of the image) I would continue, else I'd throw an exception. I'm not sure how to do that these are just some ideas I have.

Comment: @Richard: What if the 1 integer gets dropped? (Like I said, this is a hard problem)

Comment: Not all things that can be done should be done, if it feels too hard, there is probably a good reason.  Have you done any perf mon before going to such lengths to not use TCP?

Comment: You could use sequences with negative acknowledgements to get around dropped packets (or ooo packets). The nacks could be sent out of band (i.e. via seperate TCP stream) or over UDP as well. This does require that you maintain a window of sequences such that they can be retransmitted.

Comment: @richard don't let them tease you; they're goading you into reinventing tcp one feature at a time so you realize that tcp is precisely the minimum overhead that you need when you want to send things that are too long for a single packet, which is why it was invented.

Comment: @John I've seen out of order packets on a LAN. I wouldn't count on it not happening. Unfortunately I was using someone else's protocol which didn't bother with things like sequence numbers, so there was no way to know when a packet was missing or reordered. @Richard How much speed do you need? Is occasional data corruption allowable?

Comment: @Joel, not necessarily, TCP has a lot more overhead (flow/congestion control for example), UDP has the added advantage that if at some point you are broadcasting to multiple clients, multicast becomes a possibility - there are advantages to adding a little bit of reliability over UDP (some commercial messaging protocols employ this technique - for this very reason!)

Comment: There are legitimate reasons to use UDP for this; multicasting files out to many different hosts at once is a big one.  As long as you design your system to handle the behaviors of UDP (for example, including sequence numbers in your UDP packets, having a TCP fallback for missing chunks, adjusting throughput based on error rates) this kind of setup can be a big win over TCP.

Comment: Out-of-order packets do happen under UDP.  So yes, mechanisms must be built to re-assemble them in the correct order.

Comment: I'm not saying, I never did say, that UDP is "Right" and TCP is "Wrong".  Each has pros & cons, and each has it's place.  It might be enough to say that since TCP guarantees ordered delivery, OP should use TCP.  But maybe not, there are other considerations.  For example, if you need ultra low-latency and ultra high-frequency served out to many endpoints within a network, UDP may win out.  This is why every exchange in the world is moving away from TCP and towards UDP.

Comment: The academicians, who have limited experience except what they have read, would have you think I'm "goading" you.  I'm not.  I'm simply pointing out that the decision between UDP and TCP is just like so many others when designing a new system.  The answer may not be as simple as "TCP guarantees ordered delivery, therefore use TCP."  You can't simply follow dogma and the soundbytes from university texts.  You must understand the pros & cons of each, and think for yourself.

Comment: @John: Err.. as far as I am aware, the direction is more in TCP's favor, because most services nowadays are built on top of HTTP, which runs on top of TCP. The only major service of which I am aware that is moving to UDP is the [Micro Torrent Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Transport_Protocol), and then they're basically implementing all of TCP inside of UDP, but using a different congestion control algorithm (one which yields to TCP traffic). If you need reliable transport, use TCP. If you don't, then don't.

Comment: @Billy:  You are referring to one class of problem domain.  There are many applications & systems that don't use HTTP.

Comment: @John: I never said all applications and systems used HTTP, I said many applications and services are moving in that direction (namely, because HTTP passes firewalls easily). UDP often has problems getting around NAT boxes.

Comment: @Billy:  At the same time, many others are moving in the other direction -- towards UDP.  Even those that require packets in order and are sensitive to dropped packets.  So it's a wash.

Comment: If pieces of the array can be thrown away and replaced by newer pieces, the UDP may be okay (if data losses are acceptable), but the sound reasoning in the comments above should be heeded.

Answer (score 13):

You don't have to "split" the array. You just have to point into different parts of it.

Assuming you're using a typical UDP write() function, it takes several arguments. One of them is a pointer to the buffer and the other is the length.

If you want to get the first 65535 bytes, your buffer is at `wrkmem` and the length is 65535.

For the second 65535 bytes, your buffer is at `wrkmem + 65535` and your length is 65535.

The third 65535 bytes, your buffer is at `wrkmem + 2 * 65535` and your length is 65535.

Get it?

(That said, the other posters are correct. You should be using TCP).

On the other side, when you want to re-join the array, you must allocate enough memory for the whole thing, then use a copy function like memcpy() to copy the arriving chunks into their correct position. Remember that UDP may not deliver the pieces in order and may not deliver all of them.

Comment: +1 -- of course neither side will be able to detect if a packet arrives out of order, or is dropped completely. Therefore the OP will need to implement his/her own mechanism for handing these tasks.

Comment: look at the bright side: he'll learn a lot about pointer arithmetic trying to reimplement his own TCP implementation.

Comment: This is a good point... though I hope it isn't my checking account he's withdrawing from with this :)

Comment: Another alternative is to use SCTP: you can have both reliable and unreliable streams in a single connection.

Answer (score 1):

You might wish to try a message based middleware like [ØMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) and feed the entire compressed image as one message and have the middleware run asynchronously and manage redelivery at the fastest speed possible.  It provides a BSD socket compatible API and so can be easy to migrate code over and allows you to easily swap between various underlying transport protocols as required.

Other message systems are available.

```
void my_free (void *data, void *hint)
{
    free (data);
}

    /*  ...  */

size_t uncompressedImageSize = 921600, compressedImageSize = 0;
size_t out_len = (uncompressedImageSize + uncompressedImageSize / 16 + 64 + 3);
lzo_bytep out = (lzo_bytep)malloc (out_len);
lzo_voidp wkrmem = (lzo_voidp)malloc (LZO1X_1_MEM_COMPRESS);
zmq_msg_t msg;

rc = lzo1x_1_compress (imageData, uncompressedImageSize,
                       out, &compressedImageSize, wrkmem);
assert (compressedImageSize > 0);
rc = zmq_msg_init_data (&msg, out, compressedImageSize, my_free, NULL);
assert (rc == 0);
/* Send the message to the socket */
rc = zmq_send (socket, &msg, 0);
assert (rc == 0);
```